# Iterativelly combine strings and remove the first strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, windows

So I did this code in python:

```
for i in range(len(sequence)-n+1):
        all_combinations.append(sequence[i:i+n])
```

However, now I want to change this code to js, I have no experience working in js.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal translation would be:

```
for (let i = 0, end = sequence.length-n+1; i < end; i++) {
    all_combinations.push(sequence.slice(i, i+n));
}
```